# How does this fit in the "pass by value of refrences" in java?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In the code below why foo2 is null when printing its data at system.out.print?

```
public class Helper {
    public void shadowCopy(Foo foo1, Foo foo2){
        foo2 = foo1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Helper h = new Helper();
        Foo foo1 = new Foo(50);
        Foo foo2= null;
        h.shadowCopy(foo1, foo2);
     System.out.println(foo2.data);// why  java.lang.NullPointerException?
    }

    public static class Foo {

        public int data=0;
        public Foo(int data){
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Java only passes by value, so your `shallowCopy` method doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Cgraphics foo2 is null so it will make foo1 also null. it by reference and not by value. Means you entire object is null not just the data part...

Comment: @Peter `shadowCopy`, not `shallowCopy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `shadowCopy`, `foo2` is a copied reference to the same object that `foo2` in `main` is referring to.  However, it assigns only its local `foo2` reference to refer to the same object as `foo1`.  It doesn't change the `foo2` reference variable in `main`, which remains `null`.  That leads to the NPE.

To get the desired behavior, just place `foo2 = foo1;` in `main`, so you're not dealing with copies of reference variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because `foo2` is null in the main method, and you're trying to access its `data` field.

References are passed by value, so `shadowCopy()` assigns a **copy** of a reference to `foo1` to a **copy** of a reference to `foo2`. The value of `foo2` in main stays unmodified.